# How to move a nested array one position behind within a bigger nested array

Tags: python, arrays

I have a nested array in a nested array that is within ANOTHER nested array, i'm trying to move the baby nested array one position behind the second nested array.
So, for example `['ZOMB',15]` one position behind replacing the None, and the None will replace the zomb, and I'm trying to do this for all rows applicable

```py
field = [ [['PEASH', 5], None, None, None, None, None, ['ZOMB', 15]],
          [['PEASH', 5], None, None, None, None, None, ['ZOMB', 15]],
          [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
          [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
          [None, None, None, None, None, None, None] ]
```

Comment: Plz share the code you've tried so far

Comment: You probably need to show expected output, what you've tried so far and think about the difference between arrays (e.g., numpy) and lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try inserting ['ZOMB', 15] into index you want to swap with below;

```
field[0].insert(5, field[0].pop(6))
```

Output;

```
[[['PEASH', 5], None, None, None, None, ['ZOMB', 15], None], [['PEASH', 5], None, None, None, None, None, ['ZOMB', 15]], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, None, None, None]]
```

So basically you can tailor below method for your need

```
My_List.insert(index_to_insert,My_List.pop(index_to_remove))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
baby = ['ZOMB', 15]

for arr in field:
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        if arr[i] == baby:
            arr[i - 1], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[i - 1]
```

Output:

```
[[['PEASH', 5], None, None, None, None, ['ZOMB', 15], None], 
 [['PEASH', 5], None, None, None, None, ['ZOMB', 15], None],
 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood the question different than the other peers and will drop my solution here if needed:

```
field = [ [['PEASH', 5], None, None, None, None, None, ['ZOMB', 15]],
      [['PEASH', 5], None, None, None, None, None, ['ZOMB', 15]],
      [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
      [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
      [None, None, None, None, None, None, None] ]

def a(x):
    return 0 if type(x) == list else 1

new_field = []
for i in field:
    new_field.append(sorted(i, key=a))

print(new_field)
```

Output:

```
[[['PEASH', 5], ['ZOMB', 15], None, None, None, None, None], 
 [['PEASH', 5], ['ZOMB', 15], None, None, None, None, None], 
 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None], 
 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None], 
 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None]]
```